# Eigen space of A as combination of Null-spaces of $(A-λI)$ for all λs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am introduced to the various spaces in Linear Algebra.

So, the **eigen space** is constructed by the eigen vectors and this picture is particularly helpful for me in in recognizing the no. of independent eigen vectors of $A$. Because if eigen space is $n-dimensional$, then there are $n$ **linearly independent** eigen vectors.

(Though this could not say much about the eigen values, but on the contrary, if eigen space is $n-r$ dimensional, we know for sure, **r eigen values are same** for $A$.)

But, the **null-space** of $(A-λ_1I)$ will give the eigen space component contributed by $λ_1 $and similarly the **combination of all the nullspaces of $(A-λ_1I)$ will give eigen-space of $A$**.

I am not able to see geometrically, how these both are same. Please help.

Also we know if a particular eigen value is having Arithmetic Multiplicity 1, then it will have one eigen vector span. And if its $AM>=1$, then it could have linear combination of independent eigen vectors contribution to eigen space.

How to see that fact from null-space of $(A-λ_1I)$, i.e **if $λ_1$ has AM=1, how we can see that nullspace is 1-dimension**? And similarly for AM>=1 case?

Thanking you in anticipation

Comment: There is no such thing as the eigenspace of $A$. For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ there is the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$, namely $\ker (A-\lambda I)$. I just say this because I suspect you are confused ..

Comment: There is no such thing as "_the_ eigenspace". If there is more than one eigenvalues then the eigenvactors do not form a subspace.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes I was confused at $eigen-space$ of $A$. Thank you for pointing out that. But could you guide me on is there any meaning to a vector space obtained by having all the linearly independent eigen vectors as basis?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Got it! Thank you. But can we geometrically see why the Null spaces of any $(A-λI)$ don't interfere? I am saying that because I think the eigen vectors corresponding to any eigen value is linearly independent to eigen vectors of any other eigen value ?

Comment: I have no idea what it means to say the eigenspaces "don't interfere". Yes, eigenvectors for different eigenvalues are independent - this is easy from the definitions.

Comment: In the comments you seem to be asking this question. Suppose $x_1,\dots, x_k$ are eigenvectors for distinct $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$. Is the set $\{x_1,\dots, x_k\}$ linearly independent? The answer is Yes. To see this suppose $\sum a_i x_i=0$. Apply $\prod_{j\not=i}(A-\lambda_j I)$ to this sum to get $\prod_{j\not=i}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j )a_i x_i=0$; hence $a_i=0$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I have always seen the argument that a minimal non-trivial relations between eigenvectors to different eigenvalues can be shortened using the eigenvalue property of one of the vectors, but this argument is nicer. Thanks!

Comment: @BhartenduKumar : The matrix I have written down kills every $x_j$ except $x_i$ because it has a factor $A-\lambda_j I$. I really don't follow your comment.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes got it! But you used cayley-hamilton to substitute $λ_i$ for $A$ ? To convert from matrix equation to equation in numbers? Thank you

Comment: @BhartenduKumar: No. I used this (repeated) $(A-\lambda_j I)x_i=Ax_i-\lambda_jx_i=\lambda_i x_i-\lambda_jx_i=(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)x_i$. CH  has nothing to do with this, just use definition of "eigenvalue, eigenvector".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is uncommon to combine eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues into one eigenspace. It is more common to say that $A$ has several eigenspaces, one for each eigenvalue $\lambda$. These eigenspaces are often denoted $\operatorname{Eig}(A, \lambda)$ (or similar), but they’re really just the nullspaces of $A - \lambda I$ for those values of $\lambda$ where this nullspace is non-trivial.

The reason these eigenspaces are interesting is that $A$ acts in a simple way on their vectors: For $v \in \operatorname{Eig}(A, \lambda)$ we have $Av = \lambda v$. In particular, the result lies in $\operatorname{Eig}(A, \lambda)$ again. Hence, we can restrict $A$ to an operator $A_\lambda$ (non-standard notation) on $\operatorname{Eig}(A, \lambda)$ which will just be identity multiplied by $\lambda$.

If you combine eigenspaces for different eigenvalues, you can still restrict $A$ to an operator of this space, but is won’t be such a simple operator anymore. For example, if $A$ is diagonizable, the combination of all eigenspaces is the domain of $A$ again and you’re back where you started.

The proofs for the relation between the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ (i.e. the order of zero at $\lambda$ of the characteristic polynomial) and the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ (i.e. the dimension of the nullspace of $A - \lambda I$ should be part of course. (If you haven’t covered them yet, they should be coming up.) Note that these numbers are not the same in general. Instead, we have:

1. $GM_\lambda \leq AM_\lambda$ for all $\lambda$. This includes the case when either is zero (and then, both are zero by 2.).
2. If $AM_\lambda \geq 1$ then $GM_\lambda \geq 1$.

In particular, all combinations of $AM_\lambda$ and $GM_\lambda$ such that $1 \leq GM_\lambda \leq AM_\lambda$ are possible.

Comment: Great Answer! Thank you so much! Can you help on my thinking that in a diagonalizable matrix, when we write the Modal matrix $P$ where columns as eigen vectors , how the vector space of this $P$ matrix and our original matrix $A$ are related? if they are. And is this vector space represented by $P$ the eigen space by combining all the eigen vectors?

Comment: And yes the proofs are there and ok I would wait. But just leaving here my comment, if I forget after the proofs, that "why the Null spaces of each of $(A-λ_iI)$ are linearly independent to each other." Thank you !

Comment: I don’t really think that there’s much of a relation between the spaces associated to $P$ and those associated to $A$. The column space of $P$ is the sum of the eigenspaces of $A$ but that is not a very useful observation. After all, both of them are simply the entire space under consideration because that is what ‘diagonalizable’ means.

Comment: In particular, there is no useful relation between the eigenspaces of $P$ and those of $A$ as far as I know. For one, the matrix $P$ is not even unique. For example, if $A$ is diagonal to begin with, you can choose *any* diagonal matrix as $P$ (and even more matrices if $A$ has repeated eigenvalues). So in this case, you can basically freely choose the eigenvalues of $P$.

Comment: Are you really sure that the vector space spanned by matrix $A$ is in same domain as spanned by matrix $P$ i.e. the modal matrix? because for rotational matrix, the domain be real numbers, but the eigen vectors are complex, so the domain of vector space spanned by $P$ then would be complex domain?

Comment: The proof that eigenspaces to different eigenvalues are independent should also come up in your course (or as an exercise). The trick is to consider a *minimal* linear relation among eigenvectors to different eigenvalues and to use the eigenvalue equation for one of them to reduce the relation, contradicting the minimality.

Comment: Ok yes! from your eigen values of matrix $P$ logic, yes the eigen values of matrix $A$ seems independent of eigen values of matrix $P$. Great! But domain of $A$ and $P$ seems can be different?

Comment: If you consider complex eigenvalues of a real matrix $A$, you are really considering $A$ as acting on $\mathbb C^n$ instead of $\mathbb R^n$. In other words, you are thinking of $A$ as a complex matrix where all entries happen to lie on the real axis. Also, I did not claim that $A$ and $P$ span the same space, only that the sum of the eigenspaces of $A$ (which you need to compute in over the complex numbers if an eigenvalue is complex) is the column space of $P$. If $A$ is not invertible but diagonizable, the column spaces of $A$ and $P$ will not be the same.

Comment: Yes! That was what I needed, "if A is not invertible but diagonalizable, the column spaces of A and P will not be the same", and is it due to the fact that , when $A$ is diagonalizable then $P$ can span n-dimensional space and when its invertible, $A$ can again span n-dimensional space? So $A$ or $P$ are not related dimenionally here, just they are able to span the full n-dimensions?

Comment: Well, $P$ and $A$ are both square matrices of the same size (and hence act on the same vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$). But $A$ may or may not be invertible and thus its columns may or may not span the whole space (they don’t span the whole space precisely when $0$ is an eigenvalue). On the other hand, $P$ will always be invertible (if it exists).